# Enthought Mayavi embedding with wx problems

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython, enthought, mayavi

At first my running system:

I use Windows 8 Pro and Mayavi 4.3 from the repository together with wxPython 2.9.4.0 at Python 2.7.4 but also had the same issue with mayavi 4.2.1 from the EPD package...

As I try to embedd mayavi into a notebook panel I get some problems with the UI. Even in the demo file from mayavi I got the same strange behavior of external frames generated by mayavi.

So using the settings button a the settings window opens. Also the scene reacts on the parameters I changed using the settings. But after clicking OK or chancel the window does not close. And python gives back several error messages. A simular behavior was there as i used the pipeline by implenting mlab.show_pipeline() command.

This behaivior is could be found on the [sample from the enthought web page](http://docs.enthought.com/mayavi/mayavi/auto/example_wx_embedding.html#example-wx-embedding) too.

Here you can see my error message after trying to click OK in the settings frame of the enthougth example:

```
C:\my_directory\>python wx_embedding.py
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\enthougth_development_mayavi_git\traitsui\traitsui\wx\toolkit.py:35: wxPyDeprecationWarning: Using deprecated class PySimpleApp.
 _app = wx.PySimpleApp()

wx_embedding.py:63: wxPyDeprecationWarning: Using deprecated class PySimpleApp.
app = wx.PySimpleApp()

Traceback (most recent call last): File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\enthougth_development_mayavi_git\traitsui\traitsui\wx\ui_live.py", line 360, in _on_ok
self.close( wx.ID_OK )

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\enthougth_development_mayavi_git\traitsui\traitsui\wx\ui_live.py", line 320, in close

ui.finish()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\enthougth_development_mayavi_git\traitsui\traitsui\ui.py", line 264, in finish

self.reset( destroy = True )
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\enthougth_development_mayavi_git\traitsui\traitsui\ui.py", line 304, in reset
editor.dispose()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\enthougth_development_mayavi_git\traitsui\traitsui\wx\instance_editor.py", line 208, in dispose
self._ui.dispose()

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\enthougth_development_mayavi_git\traitsui\traitsui\ui.py", line 237, in dispose
self.finish()
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\enthougth_development_mayavi_git\traitsui\traitsui\ui.py", line 264, in finish
self.reset( destroy = True )

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\enthougth_development_mayavi_git\traitsui\traitsui\ui.py", line 318, in reset
toolkit().destroy_children( self.control )
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\enthougth_development_mayavi_git\traitsui\traitsui\wx\toolkit.py", line 474, in destroy_children
control.DestroyChildren()

File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\wx-2.9.4-msw\wx\_core.py", line 9203, in DestroyChildren
return _core_.Window_DestroyChildren(*args, **kwargs)
wx._core.PyAssertionError: C++ assertion "GetEventHandler() == this" failed at .    .\..\src\common\wincmn.cpp(468) in wxWindowBase::~wxWindowBase(): any pushed event handlers must have been removed
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mayvi is not compatible with wx 2.9.

More info here: https://support.enthought.com/entries/22601196-wxPython

Please use enpkg to revert to wx 2.8 which ships with EPD.

Comment: Jonathan -- I was getting the same behavior as Stephan using wxPython 3.0.  As per this answer, I reverted to wx 2.8, but am still seeing the same behavior?

Comment: This answer, from almost 3 years ago, was for a long-obsolete version of mayavi. I suggest that you post a new question, including all your relevant version and OS information, and referring back to this question.

Answer (score 1):

At least this particular exception can be solved with the changes associated with this PR: https://github.com/enthought/traitsui/pull/108.  I don't know about Mayavi and the rest of the stack yet, but that change will at least get traitsui working with wxPython 2.9.